# iCloud "message size violation" when sending zip containing more than 127 files

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, error, zip

### Revised question

As per [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)'s suggestion in the comments I did some further testing.

There seems to be a problem with iCloud and sending a zip file of a folder with a certain amount of files. There appears to be a limit of 127 files in 1 folder, regardless of file type (tried `.png`, `.svg` and `.txt`).

When sending the mail using the Mail app I get a `message size violation` error and the mail can not be sent. Using the iCloud web interface the mail does appear to be sent (no error, appears in '*sent*' list) but it never arrives.

Does anyone know why this limit exists? (as [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) mentioned in the comments it might be some 7-bit shenanigans)

---

### Old question

If I try to send an email with a 1.3 MB zip file as attachment I get a `message size violation` error:

[image: Mail error]

File sizes of the zip file and original folder (1.3 MB and 10.7 MB respectively):

[image: Info panel zip file and folder]

At first I thought it was somehow related the original folder being more than 10 MB, but according to Apple's [iCloud support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202305) the limit is 20 MB:

> ### Limits on sending messages
>
> There are several safeguards in place to make sure that only iCloud members can send messages using iCloud. One of these safeguards includes reasonable limits on:
>
> - ...
> - The size of incoming and outgoing messages (20 MB, up to 5 GB with Mail Drop turned on)

Why am I unable to send this zip file? (also: shouldn't Mail Drop kick in if it thinks the attachment is too large? It is turned on.)

Comment: I'd first just suspect 'glitch'. Try a new mail with the same attachment, & a new mail with a re-zipped version. That will eliminate a couple of options.

Comment: Sending a new mail, using a different iCloud address, restarting Mail nor rezipping the folder worked unfortunately.

Comment: Does it send if there's no attachment at all, or a different attachment entirely?

Comment: Okay I did some testing: the problem seems to be the number of files in 1 folder. The limit is 127 files in a zipped folder. The moment I add 1 more file the zip doesn't send. (regardless of file type, I tested using PNG's SVG's and TXT files)

Comment: Ahh, right. Useful info. I had no idea there was a limit... nor how the mailer would be able to tell

Comment: I'd be tempted to revise the question, as we now know 'how' yet not 'why'

Comment: Good suggestion, I revised the question. I might check if Gmail is able to handle zip files with more than 127 files.

Comment: It's a prime example of some kind of 7-bit addressing system, though why it should be so limited in this day & age is anyone's guess

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem : zipped two 11.5 MB Xojo compiled apps. Sending from me.com or sending to me.com gave the 'message size violation' error.

To bypass this possible 127-file limit, I created an empty disk image with Disk Utility. Mounted it and copied the two apps onto it. Unmounted and zipped it and sent it via me.com : that worked.

Comment: I created a tar archive of my zip file and that also worked.

From the terminal - tar - cf outputfile.tar inputfile.zip